# Package an office add-in

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I'm packaging my Office Add-in to publish it.

It seems that packaging the add-in within Visual Studio is easier than manually. But
I have not developed it in Visual Studio. The source code contains just one `.xml`, one `.html` and several `.js` files. In this case, Do I have to first make a solution `.sln` with these files?

Additionally, does [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) apply to the packaging of Office Add-in? In a test office add-in solution, first, I cannot find `package.appxmanifest.xml`, then I cannot find `Store->Create App Packages` after `right-clicking the project`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to create any kind of "package" in order to publish your add-in. The .xml manifest file is itself the only file that the Office applications need to reference (the contents of that file point to the other information).

Before you publish, you should host the HTML/JS/CSS resources at an HTTPS-accessible location

If you want to publish to the **Store**, you'll need to go to [sellerdashboard.microsoft.com](http://sellerdashboard.microsoft.com) and upload the .xml manifest file and other separate information, such as a description, category, and end-user license agreement. Here are the [instructions for submitting to the Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff075782-1303-4517-91cc-b3d730e9b9ae(Office.15).aspx).

If you want to publish to an **enterprise**, provide the .xml file to the IT admins, who can use one of several publishing methods described in the [enterprise publishing instructions](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish).

-Michael (PM for Office add-ins)

Comment: I see... So I don't need to use `Windows App Certification Kit` to verify my add-in, right?

Comment: Hi, Michael. I just posted a question on how to distribute add-ins to enterprise users (https://stackoverflow.com/q/49743745/2112866) and I was surprised that the AppSource didn't really support this. Are there any plans to expand support in the future?