# How are Office add-ins in AppSource distributed to organizations and single-users

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I developed an Office Word add-in that I'd like to make available to organizations as well as single users. I understand that the AppSource will only grant licenses to single users, and that if I want to distribute to organizations I must create my own licensing and accounting backend[[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/implement-licensing-for-add-in-services#step-2-create-a-licensing-database) and have an IT professional at the purchasing organization run a centralized deployment of the add-in.

My question deals with finding the best practice to offer the app on AppSource such that both an single user and an enterprise client can deploy the app straight from AppSource.

The rub is that I'm not willing to make my app free, which is a requirement for Centralized Deployment[[3]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment#publish-an-office-add-in-via-centralized-deployment):

> You may only add free add-ins from AppSource; adding paid add-ins isn't currently supported.

So, I'm thinking that I can't multipurpose my add-in on the AppSource and instead either:

1. Provide two add-in products in app source. One that does token checks only, and another that does user identity checks only. The second one being "free" on AppSource and Centralized Deployment friendly.
2. Only provide a token-based app in AppSource, and create a secondary manifest that I provide to organizational purchasers.

Both solutions are clunky and my aim to simplify the code base. I'm basically wondering what is the standard(best) practice(s) to provide an AppSource add-in that can serve both individual and organizational users?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd make the add-in free and use your own licensing backend to allow users to activate the functionality. This is common practice for other addins

Thanks
Phil

Comment: So, you don't use the AppSource to process payments, etc. You do it on your own backend? I guess the AppSource is just a marketing channel... `*sigh*`

Comment: Most do not. Generally, the add-in itself is free while the "service" is not (i.e. the Netflix model: free clients, paid subscription). The primary reason for this is that paid add-ins are not allowed by Apple so charging for an add-in within AppSource means you are blocked from a sizable portion of the Office market.